# Command line options and importing functions

Tags: python, python-import, argparse

I'm importing a function from a python module (using from python_file import function), then making use of that function in my system.

My problem right now is that I want the user to specify the python file and function via the commandline using the argparse module. But I am not sure how to do this. Please can someone explain how to do this?

Comment: For starters, take a look at the [argparse tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)?

Comment: When asking a question, please try to specify what you tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `argparse` is straightforward.

The trick is to import a module and one of its functions, both being provided as strings.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Import stuff')
parser.add_argument('--module')
parser.add_argument('--function')
args = parser.parse_args()

module = __import__(args.module)
function = getattr(module, args.function)
```